# How to fix query error with ambiguous column name in my example?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Show error when use `@columnsname = ID` and `@columnsname = [address]` show return value 0 don't show data I want fix error help query.

Query:

```
create procedure ProcedureName1 
    (@columnsname sysname, --varchar(50)
     @columnsvalue varchar(50)
    ) 
as
begin
    declare @sql nvarchar(max), @column_name sysname;

    /* make sure the @columnsname is a valid column name */
   set @column_name = (select c.name
                       from sys.columns c
                       where c.object_id = object_id(N'Tabl1') 
                         and c.name = @columnsname);

   set @sql = 'with cte as (
    select 
        ID
      , names
      , null as address
      , work
      , note
    from Tabl1
    where '+@column_name+' like @columnsvalue
    union all
    select 
        t2.ID
      , t2.name
      , t2.address
      , null
      , null as tt
    from Tabl2 as t2
    left join Tabl1 as t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID
    where '+@column_name+' like @columnsvalue
    )
  select *
  from cet
  order by 
      id
    , note desc
    , address;'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@columnsvalue varchar(50)', @columnsvalue
end;
go
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   Ambiguous column name 'ID'

Comment: By `from cet` do your mean `from cte`?

Comment: Note that there is no point using a column alias in the second (or subsequent) query. All the column names come only from the first `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Does using a table name prefix (e.g. `c.` or `sys.`) help?

Answer (score 0):

You have nearly answered the question in your SQL statement.

When you join two tables with column names in common, you create a situation where column names will be duplicated. If you ask for that column name, then it will be ambiguous, because SQL has a choice from each table, and it’s not going to guess.

The solution is to use the format `table.column` in your SELECT statement. In your case use `Tabl1.id` or `t1.id`, depending on whether you are using a table alias.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this statement (the 2nd part of the union query)

```
where ' + @column_name + ' like @columnsvalue
```

if `@column_name = 'ID'` that query will be

```
 select 
        t2.ID
      , t2.name
      , t2.address
      , null
      , null as tt
    from Tabl2 as t2
    left join Tabl1 as t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID
    where ID like @columnsvalue
```

The column `ID` will be ambiguous

Comment: thank all but I try with yours answer I still have a problem

Comment: @SrajMuneer can you show us the query that you tried ?